# VBA Vlookup is not working and no error popup

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a VBA VLookup to find the `Col"A"` range and copy the `Col"C"` values and paste that values into Sheets("NewSheet") Col"C" accordingly.

But i do not why its not working. Can someone please help me to find out and resolve the problem that why its not working.

**searchRange** and **Sheet2**

[image]

**searchVal** and **NewSheet**

[image]

```
Sub vlookup1()

Dim searchRange As Range

With Sheets(2)
    Dim last_y As Long
    last_y = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set searchRange = .Range("A2:C" & last_y)
End With
  
With Worksheets("NewSheet")

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To lastRow
    
        Dim searchVal
        searchVal = .Cells(i, "A")
        
        Dim w_value As Variant
        w_value = Application.vlookup(searchVal, searchRange, 3, False)
    
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You never assign a cell a value, you're getting the lookup value but then you don't do anything with it.

Comment: Like this If IsError(w_value) Then
        Exit Sub
        Else
    w_value
    End If @Warcupine

Comment: No, like `.Cells(i, "B").Value = w_value`.

Comment: Yeah, what @BigBen said, though I think you want "C" not "B". If you get an error there will be an N/A in the cell, you could do an `If` to put a 0 instead if you want.

Comment: Thank you so much @BigBen you are great. Yeah i edited it.

Comment: Thank you too @Warcupine now i understand your point.

Comment: If i want to match these both Col"A" and Col"B" then paste the result in "C" how it would be done. I am stcuk that how to write this for Col"B"

Comment: If the value to be returned is a number, then use `Application.SumIfs`.

Comment: I would either use a dictionary or create another column with the two values concatenated together and use `vlookup` on that column. If you have Excel 365 you can use `xlookup` and don't need to worry about column order.

Comment: Yes you are right @BigBen Sumif can be used.

Comment: If @Warcupine you could share an example i know m bothering you It would be great help. No i am not using 365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single column:

```
Sub vlookup1()

Dim searchRange As Range

With Sheets(2)
    Dim last_y As Long
    last_y = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set searchRange = .Range("A2:C" & last_y)
End With
  
With Worksheets("NewSheet")

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To lastRow
    
        Dim searchVal
        searchVal = .Cells(i, "A")
        
        Dim w_value As Variant
        w_value = Application.vlookup(searchVal, searchRange, 3, False)
        .cells(i, 3).value = w_value
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

For multiple column Matches:

Using a concatenated column use `=CONCATENATE(A2,B2)` and V or X Lookup on that column instead.

Using a dictionary:

```
Sub LookupbyDictionary()
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim searchrange As Range
    
    With Sheets(2)
        Dim last_y As Long
        Dim i As Long
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        last_y = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To last_y
            If Not dict.exists(.Cells(i, 1).Value & .Cells(i, 2).Value) Then
                dict.Add .Cells(i, 1).Value & .Cells(i, 2).Value, .Cells(i, 3).Value
            Else 'Not sure what you want to do in case of duplicates, I'm going to add the values
                dict(.Cells(i, 1).Value & .Cells(i, 2).Value) = dict(.Cells(i, 1).Value & .Cells(i, 2).Value) + .Cells(i, 3).Value
            End If
                
        Next i
    End With
    
    With Worksheets("NewSheet")
        last_y = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To last_y
            If dict.exists(.Cells(i, 1).Value & .Cells(i, 2).Value) Then
                .Cells(i, 3).Value = dict(.Cells(i, 1).Value & .Cells(i, 2).Value)
            Else
                .Cells(i, 3).Value = 0
            End If
        Next i
    End With
            
            
End Sub
```

Using Sumifs: `=SUMIFS(Sheet2!C2:C4,Sheet2!A2:A4,NewSheet!A2:A5,Sheet2!B2:B4,NewSheet!B2:B5)`

And modify the range to match yours.

Comment: Why this line "+ .Cells(i, 3).Value" I did not understand. in last dict(.Cells(i, 1).Value & .Cells(i, 2).Value) = dict(.Cells(i, 1).Value & .Cells(i, 2).Value). I removed this for accurate result.

Comment: It's for if there are duplicates in Sheet2 it will add the values together, If you have no duplicates that line does nothing. Just wasn't sure what you wanted to do in case of dupes so I added the two values together.

Comment: I got your point @Warcupine thank you very much